# Switching off all Folium tiles

Tags: python, geopandas, folium

I'm wondering if it's possible to **switch off** all Folium tiles that have been added to a Folium Map object. By default one tile should be selected, but could be displayed a **blank background**?

It's an option that I thinkg could be useful to **enhance the visualization** of the entities that have been laid over the tiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- you can add **tile layers** to **folium** maps
- below code adds a blank tile layer then on my system 26 other candidate base maps
- finally `folium.map.LayerControl()` allows layers to be selected including blank layer

```
import xyzservices.providers as xyz
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import folium

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))
gdf["Hemisphere"] = gdf["geometry"].apply(lambda x: "Norte" if x.y > 0 else "Sur")

# create a map
m = gdf.explore(
    column="Hemisphere",
    name="Cities",
    cmap=colors.ListedColormap(["#D94325", "#5CD925"]),
    tiles=None,
)


def filter_provider(p):
    if p.requires_token():
        return False
    if (
        "Stadia" in p.name
        or "CyclOSM" in p.name
        or "NASAGIBS" in p.name
        or "BlackAndWhite" in p.name
    ):
        return False
    if hasattr(p, "variant"):
        return False
    if hasattr(p, "ext"):
        return False
    if hasattr(p, "status") and p.status == "broken":
        return False
    return True


# empty tile layer
folium.TileLayer("", name="None", attr="blank").add_to(m)

# add multiple candidate base layers / tiles to folium map
for name, args in xyz.filter(function=filter_provider).flatten().items():
    folium.TileLayer(args["url"], name=name, attr=args["attribution"]).add_to(m)

# add control to be able to select base map
m.add_child(folium.map.LayerControl())
```

[image]